# Can't print date list from table using session.createCriteria using HIbernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

the code below was working for me last month in March 15th /2017
and now there is a message saying `The method createCriteria(Class) from the type SharedSessionContract is deprecated` after I have created new project and downloaded `Hibernate` and I follow all the same previous steps
all I want is fetch all data from the `Product` but in a Java `List<Product>` format, in SQL will be `select * from products;`

```
Session session =
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Criteria product = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
List<Product> list = product.list();
for(Product productlist:list){
System.out.println(productlist.getProductId()+
""+productlist.getProductCode()+productlist.getProductName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following instead:

```
getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Product.class);
```

`Session` implements `EntityManager` which provides access to `getCriteriaBuilder` and the JPA criteria API.

Given the simple nature of your query. Do you really need to use `CriteriaQuery`?

```
List<Product> list = session.createQuery("", Product.class).getResultList();
```

would give you a typesafe list of your products.

Comment: you mean it should be like this `Criteria product = session.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Product.class);`  I tried it didn't work for me I get message `The method getCurrentSession() is undefined for the type Session` ..my session imported from `import org.hibernate.Session;
`

Comment: `createQuery` will return you a `CriteriaQuery<Product>` not a `Criteria`.